# Probability that a system fails before another given both their survival functions

Tags: probability

Question is pretty much self explanatory. Given two components A and B, and given their survival functions Ra(t) and Rb(t), how do you calculate the probability that component B fails before component A ?

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do here. If we assume they are independent,

$$ \Pr\{A > B\} = -\int_{0}^{+\infty} \Pr\{A > t\} dR_B(t)
= -\int_{0}^{+\infty} R_A(t) dR_B(t)$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask how the middle operand comes from ? (first integral in your equation).

Comment: It is the law of total probability.